Discriminated union by top-level key and array key
I'm trying to make a <Menu> component that accepts a prop items which is one of two shapes:

Shape 1: Array<{ label: string, onClick: () => void }> - onClick is required
Shape 2: Array<{ label: string, onClick?: () => void }> - onClick is optional

It must be Shape 1 (onClick required per item) if the <Menu> is not given a onFallbackClick prop. If onFallbackClick is provided, then it can be Shape 2 (onClick is optional on each item).
I tried this (TS Playground link is at bottom of post):
import React from 'react';

type TMenuProps<UItem extends TMenuItem> = UItem extends TMenuItemWhenMenuHasFallbackClick ? TMenuPropsWithFallbackClick<UItem> : TMenuPropsWithoutFallbackClick;

type TMenuPropsWithFallbackClick<UItem extends TMenuItemWhenMenuHasFallbackClick> = {
  items: UItem[];
  onFallbackClick: (item: UItem) => void;
};

type TMenuPropsWithoutFallbackClick = {
  items: TMenuItemWhenMenuHasNoFallbackClick[];
  onFallbackClick?: never;
};

type TMenuItemWhenMenuHasFallbackClick = { label: string; onClick: () => void };
type TMenuItemWhenMenuHasNoFallbackClick = { label: string; onClick?: () => void; };
type TMenuItem = TMenuItemWhenMenuHasFallbackClick | TMenuItemWhenMenuHasNoFallbackClick;

function Menu<UItem extends TMenuItem>(props: TMenuProps<UItem>) {
  return (
    <div>
      {props.items.map(item => (
        <button key={item.label} onClick={item.onClick || props.onFallbackClick}>
          {item.label}
        </button>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

This has two problems.

On line 23, Typescript can't figure out that props.onFallbackClick is for sure defined as item.onClick was not defined in the code - item.onClick || props.onFallbackClick
The inference is not working out when I do <Menu items={[{label: 'A' as const }]} onFallbackClick={item => console.log('fallback, item.label:', item.label)} />. It thinks item arg is type any.

Any ideas on how to fix this?
TS Playground - https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wG4AocmATzCTgBUBZJAOwFcAFHMAZwB4AqgEkYSPEgAeY1gBNejFh1HiAfHAC8cEWInS28xW3YqQAdQAWbJewASKXgDEUAGxcAjdAGsAwi+BoXnAA-EYc3BB8ZsAwFs5unoF+AV5CpuoAXGFcPLzRsRDsMPEe3smBFFS09MzGEVExca6lSf6BabpwUjKGtcq6ltbG9k7Nib5tXupaAN7kcHAx4rxZOuIA2gC6FAsQrCXj5V5ZABRLIKumAJSa6gBuEMCyFAC+lTR02fV5jYXFY2VJpo4HMFucVtlTINWDYRgA5CAHQEpLY7OB7JGtFLBLKsJB3JBQV7vaqQgZWGHDByYiYpYEzOAuFDuJAuLK8GBQYCsADmpHRrCOpxuGnuj1kcDeVU+fRM5KGHHhiIBWMC9MZzNZ7M53L5AqOOLgJxFYqe-KlHxqNlMwNlUIpsOpKtpaoAPmTxNDHbwETSjpVMOxWBhgHs4DYOuIuvo5Ao7bpVCcwLksrLvpGQKobqC4EQYOwoKwjfMFnB+LJgHdVCXSyDk5FeAA6cGNkAoMBnTqi4u12v8dxFGBhrxIagaGbnRtMlkuF76ybjyd7I5wV3u+t8RsY51HF7V3u9ie6Kea2c13v8AD0A5gQ9Y+97VyuL3PV4rVZLV1elH4NkWul4cd1hmactQIABBfA4AcOA0D2DlJU2OdtwSZFAkXLt1Dg1heAgFwkCnCAeROfBMGdAAaf9xBPGcMnwSjJ1AlxnzgS9qyAA

Explanation
You were close and on the right track, but you want to use the whole TMenuItem[] array as a type parameter. Then we can use conditional types to choose whether to have a onFallbackClick based on the whole array (rather than a union of each item).
The simplest demonstration (and vast oversimplification) of the difference is here.
type A = [{onClick?: () => void}, {onClick: () => void}]
type B = ({onClick?: () => void} | {onClick: () => void})[]
type Test1 = A extends B ? true : false
//  ^? `true`
type Test2 = B extends A ? true : false
//  ^? `false`
// IE. type A and B are not equivalent. A is indeed B, but B is not of A.
// or: all squares are rectangles, but not all rectangles are squares.

Notably, you are mistaken with your first error. It is a valid error by typescript, as your onFallbackClick is not matching the type of React.MouseEventHandler<HTMLButtonElement>, you likely meant to wrap this functionality.
<button key={item.label} onClick={item.onClick || (() => {props.onFallbackClick?.(item)})}>

Unfortunately, we do need to use ?. with onFallbackClick despite the fact that in theory this would not needed. But, better safe then sorry, especially on the implementation side. (Aside: the longer explanation requires justifying Typescript's design, which is beyond the scope of this question or my qualifications).
Solution
I have renamed some of the variables/types for readability, but it should be adaptable to your problem:
type TMenuItemWithOnClick = {
  label: string;
  onClick: () => void;
}

type MenuPropsWithoutFallback<T extends TMenuItemWithOnClick[]> = {
  items: T
  onFallbackClick?: never;
}

type TMenuItemWithMaybeOnClick = {
  label: string;
  onClick?: () => void;
}

type MenuPropsWithFallback<T extends TMenuItemWithMaybeOnClick[]> = {
  items: T
  onFallbackClick: (item: T[number]) => void;
}

type TMenuItemTypes = TMenuItemWithMaybeOnClick | TMenuItemWithOnClick

type MenuProps<T extends TMenuItemTypes[]> = T extends TMenuItemWithOnClick[]
  ? MenuPropsWithoutFallback<T>
  : MenuPropsWithFallback<T>


function Menu<T extends TMenuItemTypes[]>(props: MenuProps<T>) {
  return (
    <div>
      {props.items.map(item => (
        <button key={item.label} onClick={item.onClick || (() => {props.onFallbackClick?.(item)})}>
          {item.label}
        </button>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

You can view this working on TS Playground, along with supplementary examples.

Thanks especially for pointing out that design discussion on Typescript, that nuance was bugging me lol

You can achieve this by conditionally defining items's type based on a generic type for onFallbackClick.
You'll still need type guards and/or optional chaining within the component since typescript won't be able to infer one parameter based on how the other is narrowed.
interface Item {
  label: string;
}
interface ItemClickNeeded extends Item {
  onClick: () => void;
}
interface ItemClickOptional extends Item {
  onClick?: () => void;
}

function Component<
  FallbackClick extends (() => void) | undefined = undefined, // Default is needed [1]
>(props: {
  onFallbackClick?: FallbackClick;
  items: Array<
    FallbackClick extends undefined ? ItemClickNeeded : ItemClickOptional
  >;
}) {}

Component({ items: [{ label: "foo" }] }); // ❌ onClick is missing
Component({ onFallbackClick: () => {}, items: [{ label: "foo" }] }); // ✅
Component({ items: [{ label: "foo", onClick: () => {} }] }); // ✅

Playground
[1]: The optional property's type won't automatically be inferred as undefined if it's omitted from the passed props.

This answer is good if you are OK with having all items have onClick and still accepting an onFallbackClick, but that's a design decision question sort of deal.

This is an awesome solution too thank you!
